# Асинхронное удаление выбранной строки GridView в Yii

Tags: ajax, gridview, yii, php

Вопрос к знатокам Yii. Сделал при помощи gii стандартный CRUD (http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/person/admin), но чтоб удалить запись или изменить, надо выбрать строку и снизу нажать на кнопку нужного события (удалить или изменить). Искал в документации готовых решений в фреймворке не нашел. Может есть какие примеры или подскажите в какую сторону двигаться. 
Единственный способ, что вижу это писать аякс запрос к данным кнопкам и обновлять грид.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я не совсем понял, что вы хотите сделать, если честно, для того чтобы удалить
нужно в контроллере завести специальный акшн
public function actionDelete($id) {
Model::model()->deleteByPk($id);
}

тогда после удаления грид сам обновит таблицу,
для массовой операции существует слудующая рабочая методика (не хочу переписывать, в источнике все достаточно разжевано)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083616/submit-cgridview-checked-values-using-a-form